# android random item from arraylist

Tags: random, arraylist

I want to get random item from arraylist. My code how i tried not working.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
map.put(KEY_ADD, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ADD)); --edited code
menuItems.add(map);

int index = random.nextInt(menuItems.size());
HashMap<String, String> itm = menuItems.get(index);
System.out.println(itm);
```

EDIT:

```
        int index = random.nextInt(menuItems.size());   
    HashMap<String, String> itm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    itm = menuItems.get(index);
    String randomstring = itm.get(MyClass.KEY_NAME);

    System.out.println(randomstring);
```

receiving NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

use

```
HashMap<String, String> itm =new HashMap<String, String>();
itm = menuItems.get(index);
System.out.println(itm);
```

instead of

```
HashMap<String, String> itm = menuItems.get(index);
System.out.println(itm);
```

in current code you are not initializing hashmap itm before using it

Comment: i get syntax error HashMap<String, String>();- Syntax error on token ",", . expected
and - Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token

Comment: @windblow : see my edit ,sorry i forget to add new in-front of HashMap

Comment: Well it helped solve errors in Eclipse, but running app, i get NullPointerException.

Comment: @windblow : pls post relevant code with logcat result when application is crashing then i will try to help u more

Comment: well i just realised that i have multiple keys and their values. And i want get random element just for one of those keys for example - "KEY_NAME" values. So somehow i have to make some code line like "itm.get(KEY_NAME)"

Comment: @windblow : edit your question by explain your problem more and also post relevant code and logcat if application is crashing